# How to reach SVG elements by Angular ViewChildren

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, svg

I have an svg loaded as an object:

```
<object data="assets/img/states.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="map"></object>
```

This svg contains a big png map and several rect and text elements.

```
<rect
     y="224.72084"
     x="644.87109"
     height="231.68137"
     width="101.08391"
     id="RECT_TO_GET" />
```

I'd like to get all the `rect` elements in an array just like I do with normal html elements like this:

```
@ViewChildren('rect') rects !: QueryList<any>;
this.rects.forEach(r=> {
            console.log(r);
        });
```

The problem is that the rects array is always empty. I have tried to get them in `ngViewAfterInit()` and in `ngAfterViewChecked()` without success. How can I reach the elements of an svg?

I haven't tried to get them by `getElementsById()` yet, I'd like to do it the angular way if it's possible.

The whole thing is just about giving contextual colors of each rect elements once I get them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ViewChild` or `ViewChildren` cannot support CSS selectors

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

> Supported selectors include:
>
> - any class with the @Component or @Directive decorator
> - a template reference variable as a string (e.g. query  with@ViewChild('cmp')`)
> - any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component (e.g. @ViewChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService)
> - any provider defined through a string token (e.g. @ViewChild('someToken') someTokenVal: any)
> - a TemplateRef (e.g. query  with @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template;)

---

you can get the HtmlElement from a template reference variable and start trying to manipulate it after Object Element Resource Loaded

[online example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-svg-content-queryselector)

**html**

```
  <object #mySvg data="./assets/new.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="map"></object>
```

**component**

```
  @ViewChild('mySvg') mySvg;

  ngOnInit() {
      const objElm = (this.mySvg.nativeElement as HTMLObjectElement);
    objElm.onload = () => {
        const paths = objElm.contentDocument.querySelectorAll('path');

        paths.forEach((path,index) => {
          console.log(`path:${index} , d=${path.getAttribute("d")}`);
        })

    }    
  }
```

Comment: It's not working, `this.rects` is just an empty NodeList array. mySvg contains the object html element but it seems to be empty.

Comment: Update to a new version, I manipulate SVG element after Object Element Resource loaded

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add one small thing to the answer that @Chunbin Li gave (I don't have enough reputation to comment at the moment sadly).  Anyways, in the comments section, @Perrier said that `this.rects` is still an empty nodes list.  This can be fixed by using a different lifecycle method.

When using `ViewChild`, it's common to utilize the lifecycle method `ngAfterViewInit()`.  In @Chunbin Li's answer, the function is being called in `ngOnInit()`, so most likely the SVG hasn't had enough time to render.  If you call the function inside `ngAfterViewInit()` instead, it would give the DOM enough time to fully render the SVG, and the SVG's properties will be accessible.

For further reading, check out the angular docs on [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#usage-notes).

Answer (score 0):

Did some more research and found the solution below. The fun part is that this code is in the ngAfterViewInit method of my angular component and it still **needs the window.onload eventlistener to work. Why?**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var svgObject = document.getElementById('map').contentDocument;
    var svg = svgObject.getElementById('svg48152');
    console.log(svg);
    const rects = svg.querySelectorAll('rect');
    console.log(rects);
    rects.forEach(r => {
        console.log(r);
    });
});
```

The key components are the `contentDocument` property and the `onload` eventlistener. Some useful info for future reference: [**Using Javascript with SVG**](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/javascript/)

Comment: window load event simply ensure that your SVG(#map) and the main DOM is loaded before you start trying to manipulate it